# how do i use this code to find the top 5 max numbers in a file if each number has a string next to it?

Tags: python, file, heapq

```
from heapq import nlargest

with open("winnernum.txt", "r") as f:
   numbers = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f.readlines()]
   largest = nlargest(5, numbers)    
print(largest)
```

I have tested this code and it works if there is no string next to each number because you can't turn a string into a float i assume. The string is there because each highscore has a username next to it. the program should print the winner's name and their score for the top 5 highest scoring players.

Comment: you can probably split the input .. and only take the digits from that and compute it.

Comment: Please show some sample input

Comment: @YatishKadam how would i split the input?

Comment: depending on the format of the line, so that's why show us sample input / desired output

Comment: @FilipHaglund the contents of the file is usually: ['katy'] 30

Comment: so it has the username and the score next to it

Comment: All ways store the score of the player at start of the sentence. Then split them

Comment: split("]") should give you a list .. witht eh score as the second item...

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string handling" and specifically the `split` method, you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @YatishKadam could you please show me this and where you would put it in my code? Thank you!

Comment: @Prune thanks, i will try that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not intended as a tutorial resource.  You will likely get references to particular tools, such as `split`.
  As implied in the posting guidelines, we expect you to then research those tools and tutorials on your own.

Comment: Also, as an exercise for future postings, you might try to edit this one to conform better: Give us input samples, show the desired output, and your coding attempt.  You've made a decent start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If test.txt is

```
green 12
blue 13
red 14
yellow 15
hello 16
green1 122
blue1 132
red1 142
yellow1 152
hello1 162
green2 121
blue2 131
red2 141
yellow2 151
hello2 161
```

Code:

```
from heapq import nlargest
with open("test.txt",'r')as f:
    c={}
    for l in f:
        c[l.split("]")[0]]=(float(l.split("]")[1]))
    largest=nlargest(5,list(c.values()))
    print(c)
    print(largest)
    for x in largest:
        for i in c:
            if c[i] == x:
                print(i[1:],x)
```

output:

```
{'green': 12.0, 'blue': 13.0, 'red': 14.0, 'yellow': 15.0, 'hello': 16.0, 'green1': 122.0, 'blue1': 132.0, 'red1': 142.0, 'yellow1': 152.0, 'hello1': 162.0, 'green2': 121.0, 'blue2': 131.0, 'red2': 141.0, 'yellow2': 151.0, 'hello2': 161.0}
[162.0, 161.0, 152.0, 151.0, 142.0]
hello1 162
hello2 161
yellow1 152
yellow2 151
red1 142
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204971/discussion-on-answer-by-ch3ster-how-do-i-use-this-code-to-find-the-top-5-max-num).

Answer (score 0):

A running example if the input looks like described in the comment:

```
from heapq import nlargest

test_str = """ ['katy'] 30
['max'] 45
['A'] 31
['B'] 4
['D'] 1
['C'] 15
['E'] 333"""

numbers = [float(line.rstrip().split("]")[1]) for line in test_str.split("\n")]
largest = nlargest(5, numbers)
print(largest)
```

In your case you would do it like this:

```
from heapq import nlargest

with open("winnernum.txt", "r") as f:
   numbers = [float(line.rstrip().split("]")[1]) for line in f.readlines()]
   largest = nlargest(5, numbers)    
print(largest)
```

## Edit

To avoid empty lines or lines without "]"

```
numbers = []
with open("winnernum.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        split = line.rstrip().split("]")
        if len(split) > 1:
            numbers.append(float(split[1]))
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @katy then you have an empty line in your file or a line without a ] in which case there is no split. So check your file.

Comment: @katy or you can see my edit, so you can avoid empty lines.